# Alerts with array in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How do you use a array to populate a alert list. For example if the array had a bunch of names.

> array = [john,dixy,tom,jared];

I want the alert to pop up and show those names so they can be selected from.
I am working with ionic 2.

Comment: @sebaferreras I have tried a for loop for the array inside of the alert to populate the radio list inside of the alert but that doesn't work. It gives me an error to not place the for loop inside the alert. But if I put the for loop outside its gonna give me the size of the array alerts.

Comment: ok, thanks. Are you trying to achieve something like [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/#single-value-radio-buttons)?

Comment: Yes and no. I am looking for that  but in an alert not its own page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the `alert` is created by using an object with the options, we can use that object to create the radio buttons with the names of the array.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular/index";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  private names: Array<string>;

  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) { 
    this.names = [ 'john', 'dixy', 'tom', 'jared']; 
  }

  presentConfirm() {

    // Object with options used to create the alert
    var options = {
      title: 'Choose the name',
      message: 'Which name do you like?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: data => {
            console.log(data);
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    options.inputs = [];

    // Now we add the radio buttons
    for(let i=0; i< this.names.length; i++) {
      options.inputs.push({ name : 'options', value: this.names[i], label: this.names[i], type: 'radio' });
    }

    // Create the alert with the options
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(options);
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Also for anyone trying to do this. You cannot have both radio items and regular inputs in the same alert. It is just a issue with ionic 2 I think I read in a forum they might update it. As of right now just make two alerts.